# PHP - echo not showing?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a login system. Whenever someone enters incorrect details, there should be a message being echo'd, but there isn't, the page redirects me to my index.php file. I know I have a `header();` function, but that shouldn't be called until after the if statement.

```
session_start();

include 'dbh.php';

$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$uid' AND pwd='$pwd'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "Your username or password is incorrect";
} else {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
}

header("Location: ../index.php");
```

Comment: When the browser gets a redirect, it doesn't display the page first.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's working, but after that it's redirecting you to home page using your header function. Add `header("Location: ../index.php");` inside your else condition & you will get your desired output.

Comment: I think he actually wants it to display the message and then redirect in either case.

Comment: Then he needs to use something like javascript's settimeout or php's sleep function.

Comment: That almost works like I want it to. Now when it echos the page is cleared and just says 'your username or password is incorrect'